# Azure Front Door route to app service subdirectory

Tags: redirect, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have an Azure Front Door environment that I would like to use to route a domain to an app service  sub directory. But im having some issues setting it up

Domain: portal.example.com
Back End Pool: App Service - xxx.azurewebsites.net

I would like portal.example.com to route to xxxx.azurewbesites.net/portal

But for some reason im not able to do that and getting errors if i try to have it redirect with the slash " / "

"The domain and subdomains can be between 1 to 63 alphanumeric characters, must start and end with an alphanumeric character, and additionally can contain the '-' character in between. The top level domain must be between 2 to 61 alphabetical characters."

I have tried creating a routing rule and also tried using rule engine configuration.

Answer (score 0):

seems there will be wrong route configuration. I have tried to replicate the same scenario.

Step1:
Created a front door environment with backend endpoint as
*****.azurewebsites.net

[image]

Step2:
Applying rule configuration to update route rule as
if request URL is "portal.example.com" then route the traffic to xxxx.azurewbesites.net/portal

[image]

refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching?pivots=front-door-classic) for more information.  Found another similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936330/azure-front-door-how-to-create-routing-rules) for reference.